# GWT java URL Validator

Tags: java, validation, url, gwt

Does someone knows a function that validate if a url is valid or not purely in GWT java without using any JSNI

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I am using this one (making use of regular expressions):

```
private RegExp urlValidator;
private RegExp urlPlusTldValidator;
public boolean isValidUrl(String url, boolean topLevelDomainRequired) {
    if (urlValidator == null || urlPlusTldValidator == null) {
        urlValidator = RegExp.compile("^((ftp|http|https)://[\\w@.\\-\\_]+(:\\d{1,5})?(/[\\w#!:.?+=&%@!\\_\\-/]+)*){1}$");
        urlPlusTldValidator = RegExp.compile("^((ftp|http|https)://[\\w@.\\-\\_]+\\.[a-zA-Z]{2,}(:\\d{1,5})?(/[\\w#!:.?+=&%@!\\_\\-/]+)*){1}$");
    }
    return (topLevelDomainRequired ? urlPlusTldValidator : urlValidator).exec(url) != null;
}
```

Comment: I find this doesn't validate URLs with a trailing slash like 'http://google.com/'

Comment: @Andy: just wrote a small JUnit and indeed it returns false on `google.com/` -- but it does return true on `http://google.com/` (with or without trailing slash). According to the definition of URLs, the schema prefix (e.g. 'http') followed by `://` is mandatory, thus `google.com` is invalid.

Comment: @Sven Ah, apologies, I was under the impression I was prepending `http://` but it's entirely possible that I forgot! (+1)

Comment: How can I detect urls with params ? Something like : 
`https://xyz.com/getUser.action?id=1&pwd=2`

Comment: You could use the RegExp above to test for a valid URL first and then test if the URL also contains a "?" - that should be the simplest solution. Otherwise, you would need to take the "?" from the last, optional class ([...?...]+) and make it mandatory.

Answer (score 0):

org.apache.commons.validator.UrlValidator and static method isValid(String url) might be of help here.

Comment: Note this wouldn't work for any client side GWT as Apache Commons isn't a GWT module..

Answer (score 0):

You should use regular expression in GWT. Here is similar topics [Regex in GWT to match URLs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2098750/regex-in-gwt-to-match-urls) and [Regular Expressions and GWT](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1162240/regular-expressions-and-gwt)