# URL validation regex for real-world URLs

Tags: javascript, regex, url

I want to validate that given strings are URLs. Matching URLs in text would be nice too, but not required. I've searched and experimented but so far I did not find something that answers these requirements:

1. Must not accept strings which, when treated as links, pose a security risk. For example, `<a href="javascript:alert(document.cookie)">clickme</a>` is a valid HTML element and indeed works (raises an alert and so on) in at least some browsers. I'm concerned that if I allow arbitrary schemes (see below) it can compromise security (as noted, for example, here: [What is the best regular expression to check if a string is a valid URL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/161738/what-is-the-best-regular-expression-to-check-if-a-string-is-a-valid-url#comment-8365285)).
2. Must work correctly in JavaScript.
3. Would be nice if it worked the same in Java -- I'm developing in GWT, so this would be nice but not strictly necessary.
4. **Must accept URLs which are used in practice, and not only standard-compliant URLs.** Specific examples:

   a. I want to accept [http://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Français](http://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fran%C3%A7ais), which is non-standard because of the non-English character, but accepted by my reference browsers IE(7+) and Chrome.

   b. I want to accept http://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fran%c3%a7ais, which is non-standard because percent-encoding hex should be uppercase, but again accepted by IE and Chrome. I guess I could just do a case-insensitive match -- any downside you can think of?

   c. I want to accept http://localhost/localpath/servlet#action?param=value, which is non-standard because the fragment part (from '#' to the end) should not include '?' and other chars, but there are apps which generate such URLs and browsers accept them.

   d. I want to accept URLs with any scheme/protocol (not just http, https and ftp), because all kinds of apps I integrate with and their users may need to pass such URLs. I can forbid 'javascript:' and allow everything else; if you think this would compromise security please say so.

There is a ton of questions on this topic in SO and elsewhere, but I did not find a regex which answers all of my requirements. Examples:

- [Regex in GWT to match URLs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2098750/regex-in-gwt-to-match-urls/2099169#2099169) -- Pretty good and simple regex, but doesn't accept non-standard URLs. I can handle the scheme part and the percent-encoding case-sensitivity, but not the other issues.
- https://stackoverflow.com/a/190405/96929 -- Giant regex (I ask myself if all browsers and frameworks I use can handle this size) which appears to be very comprehensive, but says it conforms to standard and I can't make heads or tails of it.

Thanks! :-)

Comment: Hmmm.. What about to validate address at the server side? For example: 1. check, that addres is http/https/ftp 2. try to ping the address from the server 3. if you received a response the address is OK else you show the user validation message that address is invalid

Comment: by the way, your browser does encode the accented characters in URL string, just copy the accented text and paste it into an editor. Some webapplictions do understand not urlencoded requests, but a proxy on the way might refuse.

Comment: @PrimosK: I have no intention of checking if the URL is a live one. Forget the extra work it would require -- ping wouldn't validate the path, query and so on, a server might be accessible to the user but not to my server, and the UI error notification would take time.

Comment: @newtover: I know, but it doesn't matter. I want my users to work with whatever their browser displays and accepts in it address box.

Comment: @Oz. you're right. That makes sense...

Comment: If you have such stringent security constraints, the validation should really be done on the server side. Don't forget that javascript code can be modified by the user all he wants (in theory)

Comment: See http://mathiasbynens.be/demo/url-regex for a comparison of some example regular expressions for URLs.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> Must accept URLs which are used in practice, and not only standard-compliant URLs

Actually the URI spec is pretty liberal and permits constructs which generally you want to exclude for compatibility reasons...

> I want to accept http://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Français, which is non-standard

It's not a URI, but it *is* a quite standard [IRI](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internationalized_Resource_Identifier).

> - non-standard because percent-encoding hex should be uppercase
> - non-standard because the fragment part (from '#' to the end) should not include '?'

Both of these are perfectly acceptable according to the URI standard. RFC 3986 recommends but does not require that upper-case be used when creating percent-encodings.

> I can forbid 'javascript:' and allow everything else; if you think this would compromise security please say so.

It would. Unfortunately there have been multiple potentially-dangerous additions to the URI scheme namespace and there will doubtless continue to be in future. Plus there are potentially ways that blacklisting features might be evaded used encoded characters and control characters.

In addition, arbitrary-scheme matching means your secondary goal of detecting addresses in text will create a false positive most times a colon is used.

Whitelisting is the only plausible way forward, so you will just have to manually permit each new scheme on a case-by-case basis. This requires some care; for example the `data:` scheme seems innocuous and useful, but potentially suffers from the same XSS issues as `javascript:`.

You will also need to know some information about each scheme. Schemes like `http` and `ftp` have a ‘server-based naming authority’: they can include a separate hostname and resource path within that host; additionally you probably require them to be absolute URIs. If you want to allow file URIs, you'd have to check that it was hostless (`file:///`). For other schemes there may be no concrete syntax required by the URI standard itself, but there might be other restrictions, for example `mailto:` must take a valid e-mail address.

> Giant regex (I ask myself if all browsers and frameworks I use can handle this size) which appears to be very comprehensive

This won't work in JavaScript because it has the unsupported `\x{code point}` syntax. Also languages like JavaScript whose regex engines work in terms of UTF-16 code units instead of full Unicode code points won't be able to handle character ranges outside the BMP.

You'd have to replace the long `\x{A0}...\x{1FFFD}` groups with something simpler like `\u00A0-\uFFFD`, and then check for invalid surrogate pairs separately, as well as the 0xnnFFFE–F non-characters, if you care about those (probably not).

Arguably you would probably already have excised any bad surrogates and non-characters at a general input scanning level before you get as far as IRI validation; there is no reason to allow them in any textual input. Doing that in a separate step makes more sense than trying to shoehorn everything into a single regex.

With that replaced, the longest part of the quoted regex is the insanely long string of digit-checking trying to validate numeric IP addresses. This is the kind of thing regex isn't good at at all. I would strongly consider not bothering with the IPv6 and IPv-future numeric addresses: even assuming widespread IPv6 adoption soon, no-one will be using them for the foreseeable future. (Do you even want to permit links to numeric addresses? Depends on what your app is doing, but often not.)

You might also consider disallowing userinfo@ hostname prefixes (since they have traditionally been of no use except for spoofing attacks), and percent-encoded hostnames (since they serve no purpose given the existence of Punycode, and don't work in some browsers).

So there is not one single answer to IRI validation, but here's the sort of place you might start:

```
(
    https?://
    (
        ([0-9]{1-3}(\.[0-9]{1-3}){3})|
        ([-0-9a-z\u00A0-\uFFFD]{1-63}(\.[-0-9a-z\u00A0-\uFFFD]{1-63})*)
    )
    (:[0-9]+)?/
    (
        %[0-9a-f][0-9a-f]|
        [-._!$&'()*+,:;=@~0-9a-z\u00A0-\uFFFD/?#]
    )*
)|(
    ftp://                                    // same again but with no ?query
    ...                                       // or port number
)|(
    mailto:                                   // specify requirements for
    ...                                       // other accepted schemes
)
```

(Case insensitivity assumed. This applies DNS constraints that are not part of the URI spec itself, though incompletely as it doesn't check for leading/trailing `-` in DNS labels, or the number range in IPv4 octets. Validating e-mail addresses is left as an exercise for the reader, as it is in itself an arduous task unsuited to regex if you want to do it rigorously.)

Comment: Whoa, thank you for this awesome answer! I'll have to go over it carefully and decide how to proceed, but even on first read it is very enlightening.

Answer (score 1):

Since you are using Java on the server side, I'd suggest you use [URI](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/net/URI.html). It will accept all the "bizarre" stuff you want and it is just a matter of `.getScheme()` to check that it is indeed HTTP or HTTPS.

And unlike `URL`, `URI` will not try to do name resolution!

Comment: I'll take a look at this class to maybe _add_ server-side validation, but I must validate on the client side to not make the user wait too long. Thanks.